# What does the 'this' point to in prototype method?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

The question confuses me for a time. Here's a simple code:

```
function A() {};

A.prototype.B=function() {return this};

A.prototype.B();
```

The result in chrome console is:

```
A{};
  >B: function() {};
  >constructor: function A() {};
  >  proto: Object
```

As I know, 'this' point to the object who called the method. So I think the 'this' in the prototype method points to the `A.prototype` (prototype is also an object, right?).

I'm wondering what does the 'this' point to in the prototype method. The `A` or `A.prototype`?

And what is the `A{}` in the result? What is the difference between it and `function A()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I think the 'this' in the prototype method points to the 'A.prototype' (prototype is also an object, right?)

In **that example**, yes. But that's an extremely unusual way to call a function on a prototype. If you called it in a more typical way:

```
var a = new A();
a.B();
```

...then `this` would be the instance created by `new A` (which `a` refers to).

> I'm wondering what does the 'this' point to in the prototype method. The A or A.prototype?

In your call, `A.prototype`. You *could* make it point to `A` instead, though, using `Function#call` or `Function#apply`:

```
A.prototype.B.call(A);
```

...because `this`, in JavaScript, is effectively a function argument and can be set when you call the function. (Except with "bound" functions [see `Function#bind`] or ES6's new "arrow" functions, which have a lexically-bound `this`.)

> And what is the 'A{}' in the result?

That's just the way the console in the browser you're using represents that the object is related to the `A` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if you instanciate the constructor `A` like this

```
var myVariable = new A();
```

then the method `B` returns the instance of `myVariable`

```
myVariable.B() === myVariable // true
```

Answer (score 0):

> `this` refers to the object that called the function.

So whatever object you create. If that object calls the function then `this` refers to it.